# SharePoint Development with SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, sharepoint-framework, 2019

We have SharePoint 2019 at workplace. I saw the documentation in MS https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/ about getting started with SharePoint Development.

Do I have to set up a development environment with SharePoint Server 2019, SQL Server for creating the apps? Or can I set the app catalog in current production environment and create the app in the client desktop say Windows 10 machine using NodeJS, Yeoman, Visual studio and gulp etc and deploy the app to the PROD region?

Do we need TFS or some kind of version tools?

Answer (score 0):

You need a environment to debug/test your solution, while you could use prod environment to dev/debug SPFx solution, you could dev/debug SPFx solution(webpart) by 'host' workbench `/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx` without developing the solution to prod.

[Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

Comment: If I use prod environment to dev/debug SPFx solution and if the app got any issues will it affect my farm.

Comment: This depends on your solution logic, customization only or the solution will change SharePoint, you could create a test site for that, while, it's recommended to dev/test your solution in dev environment.

Comment: Can I create forms, like leave request with SPFx? User submits leave request then system sends email to manager and manager approves. I have SharePoint 2019 onpremise.

Comment: You could create HTML form, insert request data to SharePoint list(rest api) and trigger workflow.

Comment: Do you have a sample one.